# Google Places API : next_page_token error

Tags: google-places-api

I'm gathering information on the location of stores.
The search is:

```
<?php
...
$url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=[my_key]&location=40.420989,-3.706812&radius=1000030&=&sensor=false';
$body=file_get_contents($url);
...
?>
```

I return a Json without problems, and indicates that there is another page of results.
I'll be back to make another call as follows

```
<?php
...
$url2='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=[my_key]&pagetoken=ClREAAAAQXKNHPVGCkTC_MdjSqi2T0KBDMWjEu4KF1Ylw1761Po-67AnNSp4zw0wXD4oocGpx4olSl4k2LyklJBl3mBF4VPmxp3IoOCHDRlXVmivaDsSEBuG_V1GvCH1gS5s0LCuy3EaFNXxUzzHhZ5ZRYNfeGHuqewR6Zk7&sensor=false';
$body=file_get_contents($url2);
...
?>
```

If I run it with the second call I get an error

'status' -> INVALID_REQUEST

But when I paste the ulr2 browser in the result is correct.

How I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: have you figured out hte problem it also returns me request denied error

Answer (score 54):

It has something to do with the timing between the requests, if you run them immediately one after the other, the pagetoken isn't valid yet, you have to wait a few seconds between consecutive requests.

This is because google's license terms don't allow you to fetch all the results at once and return them all at once to the user. You should have a user action asking for more results, which adds a delay of a couple of seconds.

Comment: @allemattio you are right this answer should be marked as correct and it saved my day too.

Comment: This is the correct answer - added a 5 second sleep before request, and all is well in the world!

Comment: I think it's a very bad behaviour... I didn't expect such a thing from Google.

Comment: (edit queue is full, otherwise I'd insert into the answer)
From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20200821074639if_/https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)): There is a short delay between when a `next_page_token` is issued, and when it will become valid. Requesting the next page before it is available will return an `INVALID_REQUEST` response.

Answer (score 12):

sleep(2) between requests will solve the problem

Comment: awesome solution!!

Answer (score 4):

Sleep(1.3) is the shortest amount of time that seemed to work. In other words the next page token becomes active about 1.3 seconds after it is returned in the previous API request.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code, I have used sleep(2) function for delay between requests, because next pagetoken needs to be validated on google server.
You can even use looping to remove code repetation.

// your query here

```
$query = "";
```

// api key here

```
$api_key = "";
```

// api call code

```
    try {
        echo $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . $query . "&location=40.420989,-3.706812&radius=1000030&=&sensor=false&key=" . $api_key;
        echo "<br>";
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $query_results = json_decode($result, true);
        echo "First set" . "<br>";
        print_r($query_results);
        $next_page_token = $query_results['next_page_token'];
        unset($query_results);
        $query_results = array();

        sleep(2);
        echo $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . $query . "&location=40.420989,-3.706812&radius=1000030&=&sensor=false&key=" . $api_key . "&pagetoken=" . $next_page_token;
        echo "<br>";
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $query_results = json_decode($result, true);
        echo "Second set" . "<br>";
        print_r($query_results);
        $next_page_token = $query_results['next_page_token'];
        unset($query_results);
        $query_results = array();

        sleep(2);
        echo $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . $query . "&location=40.420989,-3.706812&radius=1000030&=&sensor=false&key=" . $api_key . "&pagetoken=" . $next_page_token;
        echo "<br>";
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $query_results = json_decode($result, true);    
        echo "Third set" . "<br>";
        print_r($query_results);
        unset($query_results);
        $query_results = array();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $e->getCode();
        $e->getLine();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The first query will generate 2nd page token.
You just add "&pagetoken=tokenvalue" in your uri.

Sure it work. No alternative option.

Comment: I do it, but it dosen't run.

Comment: He has already added pagetoken in his URL and the solution is making time delay between subsequent requests and here(https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchPaging) is the apple official document to verify it.